# How to convert Pytorch model to ONNX model?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, onnx

I have a model that contains two-part  `encoder` and `decoder`.
Each of them is a PyTorch model.

I inference them as below.

```
features = encoder(input)
output = decoder(features)
```

and I want to convert them into one ONNX model instead of two ONNX models.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

In general you should build a new class which inherits `nn.Module` that combines the multiple models. In this case you have a simple feed-forward network so we can use the `nn.Sequential` convenience class.

E.g.

```
model = torch.nn.Sequential([encoder, decoder])

# inference example
model.eval()
output = model(input)

# save model to onnx file ...
```

Comment: then how to load the model please?
E.g. is following code right?  
 
`params = torch.load(model_file) 
model.layers[0].load_state_dict(params[for_encoder_part]) 
model.layers[1].load_state_dict(params[for_encoder_part])`